# How can i calculate the largest size of input n of an algorithm O(2log(n)) in runtime t?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, analysis, logarithm

For function `f(n)` and time `t` in the
following table, determine the largest size `n` of `O(log(n)^2)` that can be solved in time `t`, assuming that the algorithm to solve the problem takes `f(n)` microseconds]

Here is an image of a more detailed question and the table to be filled:

[image]

Comment: If you eat one pancake in a minute, how many pancakes you can eat in an hour? This is very similar problem, just function is non-linear.

Answer (score 0):

The O notation is asymptotic, so you can't compute exactly time of run algorithm. You can approximate time if you assume O = OMEGA and assume that it is good approximate for small n also and have almost one value measured.